# VS2019 MSBuild.exe - ASP .Net MVC project fails to publish when using PublishProfile, but works when using OutDir parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild

I have an ASP .Net MVC 5 project which I am unable to publish using a Publish Profile. If I try to publish it via command line with the OutDir parameter, I end up with a successful publish and a folder named _PublishedWebsites which contains the files I need.

However, if I try to publish it using a Publish Profile, it fails with the errors below. What could be the cause?

[image]

I made sure that I already have the specified assembly reference in my web.config:

[image]

Here is the Publish Profile:

[image]

This command **does not** work:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "Site.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Coach  /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0
```

This command **does** work:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "Site.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:OutDir=C:\Projects\Coach\  /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to add the same assembly references (below) to all my web.config's which were in any subdirectories of the project, such as Views folder and Areas folder.

```
   <system.web>
    <compilation>
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
          <add assembly="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
        </assemblies>
     </compilation>
  </system.web>
```